# cx_Freeze not finding some TensorFlow imports

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6, cx-freeze

I recently wrote a library (in Python 3.6) and built a GUI for it using tkinter on Windows 10. The GUI is now finished, and I'm trying to freeze it using cx_Freeze.

The setup script runs perfectly fine (or at least I couldn't spot any error message or warning) and I can get my executable out of it. The problem is, when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\profiler.py", line 22 in <module>
from tensorflow.core.profiler.tfprof_log_pb2 import OpLogProto
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.core.profiler.tfprof_log_pb2'
```

The reason why TensorFlow is mentioned here is that my library uses TensorFlow, and of course, so does my GUI. What the entire error message says is that when I'm importing tensorflow (`import tensorflow as tf`), the program tries to do `from tensorflow.python import *` and the `profiler.py` in `tensorflow.python.profiler` then tried to do the import that causes the error.

I found the file that causes the error, and when I do on IDLE `from tensorflow.core.profiler.tfprof_log_pb2 import OpLogProto`, it works perfectly fine.

Before reaching to that point, I encountered several similar problems (the cx_Freeze building without displaying any warning or error, but the .exe having some `import` errors), but I could so far fix them all by myself, mostly by adding them to the list of `include_files` in the setup script. I tried to do the same for this TensorFlow file, but it didn't work. I also tried including TensorFlow as a package in the setup script, or directly importing it all in my `main.py`, without success.

My `setup.py`is the following (there might be some unnecessary includes with it, since I tried lots of things):

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
import sys

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\tcl\\tk8.6"

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

includes = ["tkinter", "_tkinter", "numpy.core._methods", "numpy.lib.format", "tensorflow"]
include_files = ["C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll",
                 "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll",
                 "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\DLLs\\_tkinter.pyd",
                 "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\core\\profiler\\tfprof_log_pb2.py",
                 "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\profiler\\profiler.py",
                 "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\include\\tensorflow\\core\\profiler\\tfprof_log.pb.h"]
packages = []

setup(name = "Ap'Pear",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "Test executable",
      options = {"build_exe": { "includes": includes, "include_files": include_files, "packages": packages}},
      executables = [Executable(script = "main.py", targetName = "Ap'Pear.exe", base = base, icon = "images/icon.ico")],
      )
```

I tried rebuilding TensorFlow and its dependencies from scratch, but it didn't solve anything either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by creating a blank `__init__.py` file in `\path\to\python\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\profiler`. I am running python 3.5.2 and TensorFlow 1.5.0 so this solution may be specific to my installations.